# Is there anyway to check if I'm connected via a VPN through command line?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN and I'm asking this question because whenever I'm connected over the VPN I try  to do a simple: `traceroute google.com` and it doesn't bounce on the OpenVPN server. It just goes through the same route that it does without the VPN.

I tried to route http traffic through the VPN

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

and it worked. My question here is to avoid using this method every time I create a new key to a client to make sure he is connected through the VPN.

I read that you can do a simple `ifconfig -a`. If the you have some sort of `tunnel` interface you are connected but how can you be sure that your traffic is going through the VPN?

**Summary:**

I'm the client of an OpenVPN. Is there anyway I can check if I'm connected through the VPN over command line? Something like `traceroute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been googling much more than I care to admit about this matter. Here is the problems:

- A VPN is a direct "tunnel" to your VPNServer. If you are trying to
  use a traceroute it will not bounce on the server because it's a
  tunnel. It doesn't have to bounce at the "end of the tunnel".
- `traceroute` is a layer 3 utility and VPN is a layer 2 protocol. As far as I read there isnt any utility that operates on level 2 layer.

The only way you can see if you are connected through the VPN is doing a `tcpdump`on the server and see if you have any traffic going through the server or the usual `ifconfig -a`and checks if there is any `tun0`as an interface.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line you can run:

```
vpn status
```

This provides a lot of output, but, if it is connected, you will see several lines with the string `Connected` (note the capital "C").
If not connected, you will see many other strings containing `Disconnected` (note the capital "D").

Therefore something as simple as:

```
vpn status | grep Disconnected | wc -l
```

will return a string integer > 0 if disconnected and zero if connected.

Or if you prefer:

```
vpn status | grep Connected | wc -l
```

returns a string integer > 0 if connected and zero otherwise.

There are many other ways to parse this, but the key is using the output of `vpn status`.